# How to loop throgh bash function parameters and get the values at that position?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, for-loop, dynamic

I've been searching for this for the whole day and I couldn't find a working answer, so here's what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a bash function that takes undefine length of parameters and runs those through another CLI.

`refresh service1 service2`

And the function needs to take the two service (at this time) and run it through another CLI

```
nomad service1
nomad service2
```

So my current approach is:

```
for (( i=1; i <= $#; i++ )); do
    echo ${i};
done;
```

Which pretty much print the variable position rather than the value at that position:

```
1
2
```

Instead:

```
service1
service2
```

Does anyone know a solution for this? Where I can pass 1 or 10 parameters and it will get the values regardless of how many passed.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

In case anyone else wonders how to solve this. I end up doing the following

```
for p in $@; do
    # statement
done;
```

Which is similar to the second answer in the duplicate link